# Angular | Programmatically set elements attribute

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, checkbox, angular-material

I'm utilizing Angular Material to create an awesome web application.
Please consider the following code:

```
<mat-checkbox class="master" (click)='checkAll()'>Checkbox MASTER</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox class="checkbox">Checkbox 2</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox class="checkbox">Checkbox 3</mat-checkbox>
```

The code produces three checkboxes. 
When the first checkbox is checked, the two others should be checked as well. If the first checkbox is not checked, the two others should function normally.

In component:

```
checkAll() {
  // How can I programmatically set the [checked] property here for .checkbox?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution for check all that works with any number of checkboxes.
It also updates the master checkbox if you manually check all the checkboxes:

component class

```
get master() {
  return this.checkboxes.every(c => c.checked);
}
set master(v) {
  this.checkboxes.forEach(c => c.checked = v);
}
checkboxes = new Array(5).fill(0).map(v => ({checked: false}));
```

component template

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" #masterCheckbox [checked]="master" 
  (change)="master=masterCheckbox.checked">
  Check/Uncheck ALL
</label>

<ng-container *ngFor="let chk of checkboxes; let index=index">
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="chk.checked" (change)="chk.checked=!chk.checked">
    Checkbox {{index}}
  </label>
</ng-container>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/checkbox-behavior?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of doing it:

HTML

```
<mat-checkbox class="master" (click)='checkAll()'>Checkbox MASTER</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox [checked]="property1" class="checkbox">Checkbox 2</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox [checked]="property2" class="checkbox">Checkbox 3</mat-checkbox>
```

Class:

```
  //setting to different properties gives you the choice to check them individually
  property1;
  property2;

  checkAll() { 
     // this supposes that you want to uncheck in group also, if not set them just to 'true'
     this.property1 = !this.property1; 
     this.property2 = !this.property2;
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-byure3)

Answer (score 1):

Add a [checked] Property to the second and third mat-checkbox:

```
<mat-checkbox class="master" (click)='checkAll()'>Checkbox MASTER</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox class="checkbox" [checked]="checkedWhenFirstIsChecked">Checkbox 2</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox class="checkbox" [checked]="checkedWhenFirstIsChecked">Checkbox 3</mat-checkbox>
```

Initialize the 'checkedWhenFirstIsChecked' with false in your component.

And set it to true in your function:

```
checkedWhenFirstIsChecked: boolean = false;

checkAll() {
  this.checkedWhenFirstIsChecked = true;
}
```

With the [] around 'checked' the one-way binding is already created, you just have to set the value.