# How to delegate click event from div to checkbox dynamically?

Tags: angular, typescript, form-control

I have a button somewhere in the component where I execute a click event. When I click on the button, I would like in the same time to delegate other/an event click to a specific checkbox placed in other div in the component. In other words, I want to click dynamically the checkbox. Any hint how to achieve this use case?

Code DIV with Button for direct click event:

```
<div>
   <button (click)="toggleUserSelection()">{{text}}</button>
</div>
```

Code Checkbox:

```
 <mat-checkbox [formControl]="xxxx">{{displayName}}</mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: So what you are requiring is when you click the button the checkbox will be checked and when you click it again it will be unchecked (toggle) right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54441576/5468463

Comment: You didn't understand my question/the use case! Also the down voting is totally not correct! Some users have first to be able to understand the question before executing such action! It's not a duplicate at all. It's not about to check and uncheck all the other checkboxes in the component. I have an array where I save the checked checkboxes and display their names in a `div` in the component looping through it. There I have also a `button` where I can remove it from the div/array. Then the checkbox must be unchecked again as I removed it from the div/array and therefore it's unchecked again

Answer (score 0):

You need a boolean variable which will be changed each time you click in a button, and you will add `[(ngModel)]` in checkbox with that variable that we have already created.

Html:

```
 <button (click)="toggleUserSelection()">{{text}}</button><br/>                   
 <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checked">
```

Ts:

```
  text = 'Button';
  checked: boolean = false;

  toggleUserSelection() {
    this.checked = !this.checked;
  }
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/silent-sound-3njhr6?file=%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html%3A1%2C66)